# Django Class Based Views : Override form name

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I'm new in Django. I try to build a class based view in order to create an object.

The default name of the form in the template is form and I want to change it to `"ajoutersource"` but I can't figure how.

**views.py**

```
class ajoutSource(CreateView):
    model = Source
    template_name = "pmd/ajouterSource.html"
    form_class = AjouterSourceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy(ListerSources)
```

**ajouterSource.html**

```
{% for field in ajoutersource %} 
    <div class="row"> 
        {% if field.errors %}
            <div class="error">{{ field.errors }}</div> 
        {% endif %}
        <div class="label">{{ field.label }}</div> 
        <div class="field">{{ field }}</div>
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class ajoutSource(CreateView):
    model = Source
    template_name = "pmd/ajouterSource.html"
    form_class = AjouterSourceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy(ListerSources)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ajoutSource, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["ajoutersource"]=context["form"]
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply by following method

**Method 1** (Model Form)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['new_name'] = self.get_form()
    return context
```

**Method 2** (Simple Form)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['new_name'] = context["form"]
    return context
```

***Method 1 is recommended*** 
(Note: This is python 3.6+ syntax, change super() call for python 2.0+)

Answer (score 0):

Override the `get_context_data`, `context['form']` take from `SomeForm`, and change to `form_1`, you can use in template as `form_1`

```
class Something(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'app/example.html'
    form_class = forms.SomeForm
    model = models.SomeModel
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Something, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form_1"] = context["form"]
        context["form_2"] = forms.SomeForm2(**self.get_form_kwargs())
        return context
```